# Multiple functions in a For statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to pass multiple objects through the same set of functions. My current approach has many nearly identical lines like this:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

a = func1(a)
a = func2(a)
a = func3(a)

b = func1(b)
b = func2(b)
b = func3(b)

c = func1(c)
c = func2(c)
c = func3(c)
```

What I am after, and can't seem to figure out, is something like below, or something that uses map(). I believe the problem has to do with declaring dynamic variables within the function. Is there a better way to approach this?

```
def all_funcs(x):
    x = func1(x)
    x = func2(x)
    x = func3(x)
    return x

names = [a, b, c]
x = [all_funcs(name) for name in names]
a = x[0]
b = x[1]
c = x[2]
```

Comment: Issue is `c = c[2]`. You could do `a, b, c = map(all_funcs, names)`

Comment: that was a typo... sorry

Comment: Note that `names`, in spite of its name, doesn't hold the names of the variables, but their actual values. Depending on the type of the variables used (whether they are mutable or not), operating on the elements of that list may or may not change the original  values. In this, since they are `int`s which are immutable, it won't. If the they were `list`s or `dict`s for example, they would.

Comment: The type in my actual project is dataframe

Comment: Then it seems like you have a bit of an XY Problem here - there's far more efficient ways of applying a function to the elements of a DataFrame than what you're trying to do above. You should probably provide an example that actually shows a DataFrame and ask about what you're actually trying to do - instead of asking how to make something you think is the best solution (because it isn't)

Comment: Are you looking to apply some functions to several dataframes? Or some functions to several rows or columns of a single dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `names`, in spite of its name, doesn't hold the names of the variables, but their actual values. Depending on the type of the variables used (whether they are mutable or not), operating on the elements of that list may or may not change the original  values. In this, since they are `int`s which are immutable, it won't. If the they were `list`s or `dict`s for example, they would.

You appear to have some misunderstandings about how this works, so it would be good to have a look at a simplified version of your code:

```
def all_funcs(x):
    x = func1(x)
    return x

a = 10

names = [a]
x = [all_funcs(name) for name in names]
a = x[0]
```

What happens when this program is run?

- `a` gets assigned the value `10`
- `names` is assigned a list, which contains `a`; since `a` is an `int`, names will contain `10` as well, but since it's an immutable type, changing the value of `names[0]` won't change the value of `a`; `names` would perhaps be better off with a name like `values`
- `all_funcs()` is called for each `name`, but really each *value* in `names`
- inside `all_funcs(x)`, the local variable `x` is assigned the value passed to the function, which is `10` on the first call.
- then, `func1()` is called with that value, and whatever it returns is assigned to `x`
- that value of `x` is then returned
- the return value is collected in a list and once all of the calls are done, that list is assigned to `x`; note that this is not the same `x` as the one inside `all_funcs()` - they have the same name, but they are difference variables in different scopes
- the first element of `x` is read and assigned to `a`; assuming `func1()` returns an `int` as well, again that's just a copy of the value

Things would be different if `a` were a `list` and `func1()` modified the list it was passed, it would modify the original list, before overwriting it with the new value.

Also, since you're applying `func1`, `func2` and `func3` in order, `func2` will be operating on the function result of `func1`, etc. So you could just do that in one go: `func3(func2(func1(some_value)))`

A simpler way to achieve what you were trying to do (apply a function to a number of named values):

```
values = {
   'a': 10,
   'b': 20,
   'c': 30
}


def all_funcs(d):
    for key in d:
        d[key] = func3(func2(func1(d[key])))


all_funcs(values)
```

Or, a bit more flexible:

```
values = {
   'a': 10,
   'b': 20,
   'c': 30
}


def all_funcs(d, funcs):
    for key in d:
        for f in funcs:
            d[key] = f(d[key])


all_funcs(values, [func1, func2, func3])
```

Since you can also put functions in a list in Python, you can just loop over the functions and apply them one after the other.

Comment: last approach is good

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a dictionary comprehension:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

def all_funcs(x):
    x = func1(x)
    x = func2(x)
    x = func3(x)
    return x

values = [a, b, c]
results = {value: all_funcs(value) for value in values}

# Then extract the output
results[a]
results[b]
results[c]
```

Comment: Using a dict has two problems: you're forced to have integer results, and good luck if two keys are identical. @flakes's answer using `map` is all we need really.

Comment: @Guimoute Anything hashable can be stored as a key in a dict: so floats, for example, would also work, not just integers.  And any object can be stored as a value in a dict, not just integers.  If two keys are identical, I would have expected an identical result.  I agree that the `map` solution is a good one.